# powershell xml to json blank file

Tags: json, xml, powershell, converters

I'm trying to convert an xml file to json with powershell.
Until then it is very simple, however the source file seems to me bad coded and when I apply convertto-json, the structure json is empty:

XML source :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PnCG3_configuration>
  <domains>
    <domain Name="xxxxx">
      <players>
        <player targetId="00-1c-e6-02-0a-00" targetIdType="mac" label="test" middlewareFamily="gekkota-3" />
        <player />
      </players>
    </domain>
    <domain Name="xxxxxxx2">
      <players>
        <player targetId="00-1c-e6-02-0a-00" targetIdType="mac" label="OfficeChateaugiron-TV01" middlewareFamily="gekkota-3" />
        <player targetId="00-1c-e6-02-20-00" targetIdType="mac" label="test-01" middlewareFamily="gekkota-3" />
        <player targetId="00-1c-e6-02-0b-00" targetIdType="mac" label="test-test-TV01" middlewareFamily="gekkota-3" />
        <player targetId="00-1c-e6-02-20-00" targetIdType="mac" label="test-TV01-test" middlewareFamily="gekkota-3" />
        <player targetId="00-1c-e6-02-20-00" targetIdType="mac" label="test" middlewareFamily="gekkota-3" />
        <player targetId="00-1c-e6-02-09-00" targetIdType="mac" label="test-test-TV01" middlewareFamily="gekkota-3" />
        <player targetId="00-1c-e6-02-04-00" targetIdType="mac" label="test-test-TV01" middlewareFamily="gekkota-3" />
        <player />
      </players>
    </domain>
```

And Json Out :

```
[
    [

    ],
    [
        [
            [
                [
                    [

                    ],
                    [

                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    [

                    ],
                    [

                    ],
                    [

                    ],
                    [

                    ],
                    [

                    ],
                    [

                    ],
```

My code for convert :

```
$xmlObject = [XML](Get-Content -Path $o)
$xmlObject | ConvertTo-JSON -depth 100 | Out-File "$o.json"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly it is not that easy.

Have a look at this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jesusninoc/scripting-and-security-2/blob/master/Convert%20XML%20to%20JSON%20(PowerShell).md) which I have used before to do exactly what you're asking for.

Your code would change to:

```
Add-Type -Path .\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
$xmlObject = [XML](Get-Content -Path $o)
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeXmlNode($xmlObject ) | Out-File "$o.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this method did create a lot of "whitespace" noise for me.

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeXmlNode($xmlObject) | Out-File "$o.json"
```

This way recompiling the XML file did remove the whitespace and created a neat object.

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeXmlNode([xml] $xmlObject.OuterXML ) | Out-File "$o.json"
```